# sympy system of differential equations: Not Implemented

Tags: python, sympy, ode

I am trying to solve a complicated system of differential equations using sympy. I use sympy to calculate time derivatives quickly, after which I have two equations of derivatives that contain derivatives themselves. The equations are not linear and do not fit the type of equations sympy recognizes, so it throws a Not Implemented Error. Is there an easier way to solve these equations (even numerically), and get their respective law of motion (values across time)? This is probably very inefficient, so if someone know of a more efficient process, I am all ears, I primarily started using sympy as calculating derivatives is fairly quick (otherwise I spend lots of time wasting paper).

```
import sympy as sym

a,b = sym.S(['a','b'])
S1,S2, alpha, r, c1 ,c2 = sym.symbols('S1, S2, alpha, r, c1, c2',  negative=False)
t = sym.var('t')
x1 = sym.Function("x1")(t)
x2 = sym.Function("x2")(t)
lam = sym.Function('lam')(t)
gam = sym.Function('gam')(t)

p = (1/3)*a*(alpha*x1 + (1-alpha)*x2)**3 + (1/2)*b*(alpha*x1 + (1-alpha)*x2)
lagrangian = p - c1/2*alpha*x1 - c2/2*(1-alpha)*x2 + lam*(S1 - 0.5*x1**2) + gam*(S2 - 0.5*x2**2)

FOC_x1 = sym.diff(lagrangian,x1) 
FOC_x2 = sym.diff(lagrangian,x2)

x1_lam = sym.solve(FOC_x1,x1)[0]
lam_x1 = sym.solve(FOC_x1,lam)[0]

x2_gam = sym.solve(FOC_x2,x2)[0]
gam_x2 = sym.solve(FOC_x2,gam)[0]

dx1_dt = sym.diff(x1_lam,t).subs(lam,lam_x1)
dx2_dt = sym.diff(x2_gam,t).subs(gam,gam_x2)

x1dot = sym.Derivative(x1,t)
x2dot = sym.Derivative(x2,t)

eq = [sym.Eq(x1dot,dx1_dt),sym.Eq(x2dot,dx2_dt)]

sym.dsolve(eq)
```

To clarify:
My state variables are S1 and S2, respectively, my control variables are x1 and x2, respectively, and finally my costate variables are lam and gam, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite able to identify what your dependent variables are, `x1` and `x2`?
For numerical integration of a (system) of first order ordinary differential equations expressed as SymPy expressions you might be interested in using [SymbolicSys](http://bjodah.github.io/pyodesys/pyodesys.html#pyodesys.symbolic.SymbolicSys) (example found [here](https://github.com/bjodah/pyodesys/blob/master/pyodesys/tests/test_symbolic.py#L105)) from [pyodesys](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodesys).